# importing contents from google spreadsheets to MySql using php

Tags: php, mysql, spreadsheet, import, worksheet

I need to import the worksheets from `google spreadsheets` and store it in `MySQL`.I have tried the code available with `zend_gdata_library`,but i am getting lot of errors on it.

Can anybody help me to get the `spreadsheet key` and `worksheet id` of a particular worksheet using PHP code?Then i hope i can able to do it.

Thanks in advance,please send me your suggestions if any..

Comment: Post the code, Post the errors that you see. No one can teach you using their precious time while your knowledge about programming languages is unknown.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever want to do this??

Comment: Did you look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html#zend.gdata.spreadsheets.listspreadsheets

There is an example how you can list all spreadsheets from the user account you are accessing. Do a var_dump($feeds) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a persistent connection to the live data? If not just download them as CSV and import to MySQL using the CSV import function. If you need access to live data then you'll need to post your code.